# How to esimate the mean and variance of data from a Pareto distribution

Tags: unbiased-estimator, scipy, pareto-distribution

I have large sample of data that is approximately from a Pareto distribution with unknown parameters.  Unfortunately the distribution is sufficiently heavy tailed that just taking the sample mean is not a good estimate.  What is a good way to estimate the mean and variance in this case?

Comment: Because it's only "approximately" Pareto, and the quality of any procedure relying on such a distributional assumption is likely to be *strongly* sensitive to departures from being exactly Pareto, it would be difficult to suggest an objective solution.  Because the sample is large, why wouldn't the sample mean be good?  "Large" and "good" in what senses, specifically?

Comment: @whuber  The problem with the sample mean can be seen by reporting the mean every time $10^6$ values are summed.  The mean changes quite a lot when rare but large values are encountered.

Comment: The problem is evident, but you haven't yet supplied any information to let us assess how big it might be or to identify likely alternative estimators.

Comment: @whuber what sort of information would be useful? My sample is of size 10 million.

Comment: Do you really need to estimate the mean and variance of your sample or could another notion and scale (e.g. median and median absolute deviation) be of use ?

Comment: @Pohoua Sadly I do need the mean. How about if I did an MLE estimate of the parameters of the Pareto distribution. Is that a reasonable thing to do?

Comment: Yes, I think it could be reasonable, but it depends on how close your data's distribution is to a Pareto, and also on how heay tailed your Pareto distribution is. If you get the shape parameter close to 1 (or 2), that would be bad for the estimated expectation (or variance)..

Comment: @Simd any chance you can share (a sample of) the data here?   Or at least show some descriptive stats / plots